# Nitroshare Folder Corruption During Transfer

Tags: audacity, nitroshare

When I transfer an Audacity data folder & AUP file using Nitroshare the AUP file will not open. I get an error that Audacity can not locate the data folder. I have checked the data folder to find that it has been changed (extra folders installed & AU files renamed) during transfer. I think this is the problem but don't know why this happens. Please help.
I have used “sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder” but this does not help. I have exported the audio as wav and then transferred it using Audacity. The wav audio file transfers without any issues. I am not sure when doing things this way, whether or not the final quality is effected in any way?

Comment: Could it be a permissions/ownership issue? Maybe try chown to take ownership of the newly transferred files. I regularly transfer Audacity profiles and have no issues, but I do so manually.

Comment: On another post of mine it was suggested to upgrade to Lubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have managed to upgrade my HP 255, but my Fujitsu esprimo will not boot after install. Nitroshare is not supported on Lubuntu 20.04. To get around this issue I am now using simple http server from 18.04 to 20.04.